# ¿Cómo Localizar Sonido en C#?

Tags: c#

estoy creando un tipo de "Alarma", Pero quiero instalar el software en otro PC, 
¿cómo puedo subir el sonido a mi software y darle una dirección con el `player.sounLocation`? .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes colocarlo como recurso en tu proyecto y leerlo desde ahi

Comment: En que parte del visual studio sale

Comment: Agregas el archivo a tu proyecto, luego en propiedades del mismo hay una opcion que dice **Build Action**  seleccionas Resource, adicionalmente te recomiendo que busques un poco de información acerca de Como leer Recursos, ya que hay varias formas de hacerlo

Comment: Si, pero la pregunta es cómo "subo" el sonido, en qué parte del visual? en resources?

Comment: Creo que ya se que es, lo tengo en .MP3 y toca .wav

Answer (score 3):

Puedes subir los archivos de audio junto a tu .exe y usas

[Application.StartupPath Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.startuppath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

esa propiedad podrias asignarla en el `SoundLocation` y permite definir la ruta completa donde esta el .exe

Pero si necesitas ponerlo en una carpeta podrias unirla usando

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "AudioFiles");
```

ese `AudioFiles` seria la carpeta que pones junto al .exe y alli tendras los audio, cuando distribuyas la app a los cliente solo lleva esa carpeta con la aplicacion

El tema con la integracion de los audios en el Visual Studio se puede realizar pero vas a tener que crear un `Build Action` para copiarlos a la carpeta `\bin\debug` y poder usarlos cuando ejecutas desde el VS, no es problema cuando realices el deploy en la pc de los usuario, pero si cuando ejecutas desde el Visual Studio.

Sino vas a usar carpetas se puede definir el `Copy to output directory`, pero si tienes estructura con carpeta no aplica, alli si debes crear el build action usando el `copy`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias.